# Intermittent 503 errors in varnish cache server due to backend fetch failure

Tags: varnish, http-status-code-503, varnish-4

### ***Intermittent 503 errors in varnish cache server due to backend fetch failure***

I am getting 503 backend fetch failed errors intermittently after many successful requests. They keep on occuring at random times.

this is the varnish log sample for error:

- << Request  >> 28612478
- Begin          req 28612475 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1469259438.392350 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1469259438.392350 0.000000 0.000000
- ReqStart       10.201.1.11 49351
- ReqMethod      GET
- ReqURL         some url
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ReqHeader      Content-Type: application/json
- ReqHeader      Host: SomeHost
- ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
- ReqHeader      User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.201.1.11
- VCL_call       RECV
- ReqURL         some url
- ReqURL         some url
- VCL_return     hash
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       MISS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 28612479 fetch
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1469259441.892771 3.500421 3.500421
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespStatus     503
- RespReason     Backend fetch failed
- RespHeader     Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 07:37:21 GMT
- RespHeader     Server: Varnish
- RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 28612478
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1469259441.892804 3.500454 0.000034
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 285
- Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
- RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
- Timestamp      Resp: 1469259441.892848 3.500498 0.000043
- ReqAcct        776 0 776 242 285 527
- End

I have tried tuning so many parameters, but not able to get rid of these errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your .vcl?

Comment: The vcl file is in this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0FHWYtDKpo4dGJyOGFvYnZZVFE/view?pref=2&pli=1

Comment: @Redithion it is talking to six backend servers.

Comment: I can't see any problem in the Varnish config. Have you tried with less backend servers? Maybe the problem is one of them

Comment: all the backend servers are healthy all the time!

Comment: ok, but perhaps Varnish is having trouble to handle all of them